# A good polynomial expansion of Bessel $I$ of $\log(x)$

Tags: logarithms, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am trying to find a good polynomial expansion of Modified Bessel function of Log(x);  $$I_{i}(\operatorname{Log}(x))$$ for $i=(0,10)$. On plotting it on Mathematica as a function of $x$, I find the trend to be linear for $x>1$, but I was wondering if there is any good literature on these expansions with greater accuracy.

Comment: When choosing polynomial approximation, you need to think what you want to minimize

Answer (score 1):

*Probably not an answer.*

For easier notation, let $x=1+t$.

You probably observed that

$$I_n(\log (t+1))=\frac{t^n}{(2 n)\text{!!}}\left(1-\frac n 2 t+\sum_{i=2}^\infty a_i^{(n)} t^i \right)$$ I have not been able to identify the patterns for the coefficients $a_i^{(n)}$ which appear in
$$P_n=\sum_{i=2}^\infty a_i^{(n)} t^i $$ 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n \\
 0 & \frac{t^2}{4}-\frac{t^3}{4}+\cdots \\
 1 & \frac{11 t^2}{24}-\frac{7 t^3}{16}+\cdots \\
 2 & t^2-t^3+\cdots \\
 3 & \frac{29 t^2}{16}-\frac{65 t^3}{32}+\cdots \\
 4 & \frac{173 t^2}{60}-\frac{73 t^3}{20}+\cdots \\
 5 & \frac{101 t^2}{24}-\frac{287 t^3}{48}+\cdots \\
 6 & \frac{81 t^2}{14}-\frac{64 t^3}{7}+\cdots \\
 7 & \frac{731 t^2}{96}-\frac{849 t^3}{64}+\cdots \\
 8 & \frac{349 t^2}{36}-\frac{665 t^3}{36}+\cdots \\
 9 & \frac{481 t^2}{40}-\frac{1991 t^3}{80}+\cdots \\
 10 & \frac{482 t^2}{33}-\frac{359 t^3}{11}+\cdots
\end{array}
\right)$$

I suppose that some polynomial fit could be interesting to perform since  these coefficients vary in avery smooth manner.

Comment: But this is of no use, because if you notice the coefficients of the higher order terms are of same order, so you can't really truncate it.

Comment: @Jaswin. I never wrote that I should truncate anything. All the summations are up tp $\infty$.